# How to display the column1 text on column2 image in Gridview using c#

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I have two columns in my database(Column 1: text ,column 2: image). Now I need to Display image, and on that image I need to display column1's text, Finally the Result should  be like this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En0T4.jpg)

Here Healthy foods is my column1's text and background is column2's image.

I am using C# and Winforms.

Comment: What you've tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Unable to display the text on image @Irshad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bringing your data from database to datatable after

```
 byte[] fileContents = (byte[])dts.Rows[0]["image"];
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileContents);
                var biId = new Bitmap(memoryStream);
                Bitmap bitMapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(biId);   
                Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
                graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
                SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                SolidBrush greenBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);       
                RectangleF yourtextmessage= new RectangleF(285, 20, 250, 250);


                    graphicImage.DrawString(dts.Rows[0]["text1"].ToString() + " ,", new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.White, yourtextmessage);


                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                bitMapImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                graphicImage.Dispose();
                bitMapImage.Dispose();
```